# Xcode 8 no warning for assigning NSString to NSInteger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm not sure when this started but it seems like Xcode is not giving me type mismatch warnings/errors like it used to. For example, I just discovered a bug in my code where I was assigning the result of a method that returns `NSString *` to an `NSInteger`. The method prototype is correctly defined but the compiler gave no warning. Here is the code:

```
+ (NSString *)countryDialPrefix;

NSInteger prefix = [CountryCodes countryDialPrefix];
```

Here are the warnings set for all languages:

[image: Apple LLVM 8.0 - Warnings - All languages]

Comment: You should share an example that is not producing that warning. In my code, I get "warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') with an expression of type 'NSString *__strong' [-Wint-conversion]". And that's controlled by the "Implicit Integer to Pointer Conversions" option. If you do a cast, or something like that, that can suppress warnings.

Comment: I tried the code sample in your revised question in Xcode 8.0 (8A218a), and with this "Implicit Integer to Pointer Conversions" turned on, I see the warning I describe above. I'd suggest you try creating a new project with a [small reproducible example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. Maybe there's something curious in your project that is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This was in "Other Warning Flags" at the Project level:

`-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer unix`

So I removed the -w and that fixed it.